# Как на английском Stack Overflow встраивать запускаемый код?

Tags: обсуждение, stackoverflow

Тут это делается через "Фрагмент кода на Java/Script..." как это делать на английском?

Comment: Точно так же. А вообще такие вопросы надо задавать во первых на Мете, во вторых на английской

Comment: Буквально, точно так же. Посмотрите как выглядит кнопка "тут" и найдите точно такую же кнопку на том же месте "там". Если по всплывающей подсказке ориентироваться, то ищите, где есть слово snippet ("фрагмент кода").